# Creating Plain format pages using asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

In web application [asp.net] can we display the data in plain format. I mean i want to displya  report in a plain text format. Is there any reference to study. Thank you.

[image]
in a plain text format.

Comment: I don't understand what you want. Please try to describe better what you want to do, maybe an example could help.

Comment: Sorry for that i am placing screent shot please find

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by :

1. Write your report to some folder UNDER your web application in plain text format (the extension should be .txt)
2. Create a link with target path to your text file created. For ex. if your file name is TextFile.txt and it resides inside Report folder, then your link can be something like below.

   <a href="Report/TextFile.txt">Click to see report</a>
3. Test the approach. Just click on the link and you will see that your text file is visible in the browser itself. I have tested this on major browser like Internet Explorer, Firefox, Opera and Google Chrome.

If this works, please mark as answer.